# Does spreading traffic across content improve performance or server load?

Tags: performance, dynamic, static

Is a 1000 users looking at 100 unique pages easier on the server than if they were all served the same page? Is there a difference if the unique page were dynamic, but the 100 pages were static?

I'm not sure how to test this, but if someone understands the way servers handle traffic as it relates to processor and memory, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static content has a couple advantages. First, no processing required. Second, static pages are cached in the browser so that duplicate visits don't draw as much on the server either. You can see the page below for some tests and results.

I don't know if there's a difference between 1 static pages and 100 static pages.

http://bitflop.com/document/117